# Trying to DELETE FROM <Table> using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to DELETE FROM  using SQLAlchemy.  Error is sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: subject table for an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE expected, got 'organization'.

organization is the name of the table I am trying to delete from.

This for a utility that takes a list of tables from one database instance and copying  the rows to another database instance--but I want the target table to be empty--the user logged in is not an admin so can't do a TRUNCATE.  If there is a better way, I'm open.   Thanks.

Calling code stub:

```
for item in table_list:
    process_tbl(engine_in, engine_out, item["table"])
```

called function:

```
def process_tbl(engine_in, engine_out, table):
    pd = pandas.read_sql(table, engine_in)
    print(pd.columns)

    stmt = delete(table)
    print(stmt)

    rows = pd.to_sql(table, engine_out, if_exists="append", index=False)
    print("Table: " + table + " inserted rows: " + str(rows))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could not get the `delete(table)` call to work, but because it was a simple delete statement, I was able to use:

```
command = "DELETE FROM " + table
engine_out.execute(command)
```